# Why is Google MapView in my release signed android application works only on the emulator but not on my device

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview

I've developed an android application which uses the Google MapView.
during the development phase (with the debug key), the application worked fine both on the emulator and on my device.

Now, prior to releasing my application I've done the following steps:

1. Opened a new Google account (for 
   the company)
2. Created a new key store using
   keytool for my release builds
3. Generated an MD5 for my release
   key (using keytool -list)
4. Registered the MD5 with the
   Google Maps API
   (http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html)
   while I was signed in using my new
   Google account.
5. Changed all the apikey elements
   of my MapViews to the newly generated
   one.
6. Exported my application from
   Eclipse using the ADT add-in
   (Project->Export->Export Android
   Application)
7. In the wizard, I signed my
   application using my release key.
8. Installed the application on my
   device using (adb install)

For some reason, the MapView is not loading any tiles, as if the key I entered is incorrect.
I've repeated the above steps more then 3 times, for the same results.

Please Note,

1. My android manifest contains the
   INTERNET permissions
2. Nothing was changed other than
   signing the application.

Launching the application from Eclipse using the emulator, the MapView works great. even though the apikey element contains the key generated for my release keystore.

Any suggestions??

Comment: @Moshe-Levi Is by any chance internet access of the real device (phone) disabled when you are running the app?

Comment: You're almost certainly not running the version of the app you think you are (if you're using your production Maps API key straight from Eclipse with the debug signing, it *shouldn't* work). Try an adb uninstall of your app from both the device and emulator before a install -- you can't install a production-signed app over a debug-signed one, or vice versa, but the failure is usually silent (it'll show in the Eclipse Console but that's it).

Comment: @Ogre_BGR : I have an internet access, the application is fetching some data before loading the Activity that contains the MapView

Comment: @Yoni : Before uploading the signed app to my device I uninstalled any previous installations.

Comment: @Yoni Samlan: From the command line you can't install any apk over one with the same name, irrespective of how the two were signed. The adb will display 'Failure {INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS].  To be sure of the uninstall, I'd do it from the device itself, using Settings/Applications/Manage Applications.

Comment: @Moshe BTW what is the device you are using?

Comment: @Yoni: I uninstalled all the previously installed versions from the emulator, cleaned the project and pressed the Run button in Eclipse and the MapView works even though the apiKey is the release one. what am I missing..?

Comment: @NickT : Did it from there as well

Comment: @Ogre_BGR : Samsung Galaxy S, but I doubt that the problem is in the device. as I said, the debug version worked great.

Comment: @NickT actually, you can install an app on the command line over an already-installed one signed with the same key if you add the `-r` flag to `adb install`.

Comment: @Yoni - Yes, you're right about the -r flag. However you should get an error displayed if you try to install a signed version over a debug one. I get: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]

Comment: @Moshe: I don't suppose you set the API key in the code as well as the XML and forgot about doing so?

Comment: @NickT yeah, like I said, it has to be over one signed with the same key for the "-r" flag to work.